# Debug -> Windows -> Memory for a Unity project?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, memory, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-debugging

I need to inspect memory content for a Unity project while debugging it.

No matter what I try, such as *Use managed compatibility mode*, the Memory window desperately shows:

```
Unable to evaluate the expression.
```

**Question:**

Is it possible at all to inspect memory using the Memory window for a Unity project?

Comment: You can try to use Unity Profiler, is a good tool to inspect memory content for a Unity Project.

Comment: [Here](https://grendelgames.com/in-depth-memory-debugging-for-unity/) you can find some guiding steps for debugging in Unity and regarding Memory management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Debug -> Windows -> Memory for a Unity project?

**Actually**, in unity project,memory window cannot catch managed code automatically, you should use **Watch** Window to get the address of the variable and then input the address on **Memory Window** to get it.

**Suggestion**

**First of all**, please enable these options from [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/memory-windows?view=vs-2019).

**1)** set a **breakpoint** on the variable of Unity project and when the breakpoint be hit, you could open **Watch** Window, and use `&` to get the address of variable like this:

[image]

**2)** Then copy the address in the Memory Window and you can see the memory content about it:

[image]

**Besides**, you could also try to use [Unity Profiler](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html) just as **Lotan** recommended to watch the memory content.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trick which has let me see unmanaged memory which is used in managed code:

- attach one VS as Unity Debugger, pause, get variable address from Watch window;
- attach another VS as native debugger, pause, put address into a
  Memory window.

To interact with VS in Unity debugger mode just hit "Continue" in native debugger.