# How to list symbols in visual studio?

Tags: .net, windbg, visual-studio-debugging

I am very familiar with WinDbg windows debugger and I like to list symbols (global variables) and all memory content.

How do I do that in Visual Studio debugger when debugging a .NET application. What if I want to see the contents of ServiceProvider or some global dependency injection container during runtime?

I have breakpoint in runtime but I can only see local variables and values and have no clue how to check container object.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**When** you under visual studio debug, you can enter **Debug**-->**Windows**-->**Modules**, and then you can check all the symbol files in that window.

[image]

If you want to check the memory content, you can use the **Diagnostic Tools**.

Under **Debug**, first click the camera icon to **take Snapshot** and the memory info about your project is under there.

[image]

**Also**, you can check Disassembly window under **Debug**-->**Windows** to check the info.

**Besides**, you can also use [memory window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/memory-windows?view=vs-2019) and here is [a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63321940/debug-windows-memory-for-a-unity-project/63338040#63338040).